# Calling a script in html and typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a script in my html file as this

```
              <script>
            if (window.TamaraProductWidget) {
      
              window.TamaraProductWidget.render();
            }
          </script>
```

I did this in my ts class to import the script src

```
      this.myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
  this.myScriptElement.src = "https://.....-widget.min.js";
  document.body.appendChild(this.myScriptElement);
```

How do I call it in my typescript class? Since it's not working, but if I call  `window.TamaraProductWidget.render();` in console of browser it works well.

Comment: How did you import the script file? You need it above your `<script>` tag.

Comment: You need ambient declarations so TypeScript knows the shape of `TamaraProductWidget` and that it's available in the global object

Comment: Make sure to import that widget script before that inline script is run.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? That's a sentence you should avoid, we know you're here because something is not working. Instead, explain how it isn't working. Do you have a TypeScript error? A runtime error?

Comment: Whoever closed this question as a dupe should be more careful. The question is about TypeScript, now about how to load a script dynamically. Notice they are able to call `window.TamaraProductWidget.render();` from the console without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like `TamaraProductWidget` provides TypeScript definitions.  The best you can do is tell TypeScript that it's available globally as `any`.

```
// This does not create a var statement, 
// it just tells TS that the object is available globally
declare var TamaraProductWidget: any;
// No TypeScript errors
window.TamaraProductWidget.render();
```

[See example on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8AqUC2soAUYHtgBXMAFwHUBLYAcxFIC54oA7ATwG4AoLgd0pbB8vAHTosMXAWJkqteiLiCQMABQBKDkA)

I recommend you ask the TamaraProductWidget team to provide TS definitions.